# Magento 2.1.7 Development environment is slow

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I did a fresh install of magneto 2.1.7 with the following stack:

- OS: Windows 7
- PHP: 5.6.3
- MySQL: 5.0.12
- Apache: 2.4.25

Enabled the developer mode & disabled the cache. The customer site takes around 8-10 sec to load.The admin taken 6-8 sec to load. Created a module and was able to get it up. However any changes to CSS of the module , results in re deploying the static files with the CLI (takes around 4-5 minutes) and on refresh page takes 8-10 seconds. So development has become time consuming.

Later, I tried to improve the dev performance:

1: upgraded PHP to 7.0.18

2: increased memory_limit in php.ini (10 GB)

3: Workflow type : client side less compilation

4: Merging, minifying and bundling js has been disabled.

The performance was enhanced by a second, but that's not particularly helpful. The delay is hindering my performance.

What am I missing?